# Getting Errors but Lost on meaning using Linux Compiler

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, compiler-warnings

I built my program using codeblocks, but for school we are supposed to compile via a linux system. I got these slew of errors here down below ibut im having trouble with 149. I have no idea what its complaining about. Maybe someone could help me?

```
In file included from matrix.cpp:9:0:
matrixClass.h: In member function âT Matrix<T>::GetData(int, int) const [with T = int]â:
matrixClass.h:149:17:   instantiated from âstd::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const Matrix<int>&)â
matrix.cpp:22:13:   instantiated from here
matrixClass.h:131:16: warning: converting to non-pointer type âintâ from NULL
```

My code is below.

```
T GetData(int row, int column) const
{
    if (row>=0 && row<numrows() && column>=0 && column<numcols())
    {
        return pData[GetRawIndex(row, column)];
    }
    return NULL;
}

//Output matrix arrays here.
friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Matrix<T>& matrix)
{
    os << "[";
    for(int i = 0; i<matrix.numrows(); i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < matrix.numcols(); j++)
            os << matrix.GetData(i,j) << " ";

        os << endl;
    }
    os << "]" <<endl;
    return os;
}
```

Comment: Line 131 of myheader
Because NULL is an int, so it will convert to an int
But it's meant for pointers im assuming?

Comment: That's just a warning (though `-Werror` is always a good idea). `NULL` is meant for pointers, not `int`s.

Comment: Yeah as for the errors im completely lost.

Comment: better return a meaningful value(for example -1 etc) or throw exception instead of return NULL

Answer (score 2):

There are no errors. That's just a single warning. The lines tell you:

1. Which file included the file with the warning.
2. Which template function the warning occurred.
3. In which function that template function was instantiated.
4. The line at which the instantiation occurred.
5. The warning itself.

The warning is telling you that you're returning `NULL` when the return type of your function is `int` (`T = int`). Although `NULL` just gives you `0`, the compiler is well aware that `NULL` is only supposed to be used with pointers and gives you a warning that you're probably doing something wrong.

Comment: So i went ahead and changed  'return NULL;' to 'return 0;'

Answer (score 2):

First of all, the code is correct, although probably not what you really meant, which is why the compiler is warning you.

In C++, `NULL` is defined to be `0` (integer 0), so in your instantiation of `Matrix<int>`, if the user tries to access an element out of bounds you will return 0 (integer value 0). `NULL` is used to indicate a pointer that does not refer to valid memory, and the compiler is seeing that you are using that in a return statement... so it wonders whether you really meant to return a pointer or the value 0...

This begs the question, *why are you returning `NULL`? did you really mean to return 0?* Because if you didn't the compiler just helped you finding a bug...